# How can I build a ZIP file and deploy it to an Azure Windows VM?

Tags: github, github-actions, action

I am trying build a ZIP file and deploy it to an Azure Windows VM. This is my workflow:

```yaml
name: Test

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 14

      - name: Npm
        run: |
            npm install -g @angular/cli@10.0.0
            npm install
            ng build --prod

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
            name: Test
            path: '${{ github.workspace }}/Test/dist'

      - name: Deploy new 
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
           host: '20.xxx.xx.xx'
           username: 'azureuser'
           password: 'Nopassword@123456'
           script: |
              scp '${{ github.workspace }}/Test/dist C:\Server\Front\public\'
```

I get this error:

```
+++++++++++++++++++STARTING PIPELINES+++++++++++++++++++
SSH-SCP-SSH no first_ssh input found
+++++++++++++++++++Pipeline: RUNNING SCP+++++++++++++++++++
Connect error
[Errno 110] Connection timed out
+++++++++++++++++++END PIPELINES+++++++++++++++++++
```

How can I fix this? Or is there any other method to deploy a ZIP file to an Azure Windows VM?

Comment: To `scp`, use https://github.com/appleboy/scp-action.

Comment: I have used scp command which you provided i am getting error 2023/04/11 15:41:19 error copy file to dest: 172.xx.xx.xx.xx, error message: dial tcp 172.xx.xx.xx.xx: i/o timeout

Comment: Please edit your question and add your new workflow under an UPDATE heading. Thanks! From your existing workflow, your new workflow may look like the first one in this example section: https://github.com/appleboy/scp-action#example.